# HAPI FHIR with docker-compose: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /app/target

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, hl7-fhir, hapi

Trying to run a HAPI FHIR Server with docker-compose from https://github.com/hapifhir/hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter, but I keep getting an error:

> Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /app/target
> hapi-fhir-jpaserver-start    |  at   java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
> hapi-fhir-jpaserver-start    |  at   java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
> hapi-fhir-jpaserver-start    |  at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
> hapi-fhir-jpaserver-start    |  at   java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:397)
> hapi-fhir-jpaserver-start    |  at   java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:700)
> hapi-fhir-jpaserver-start    |  at   org.h2.store.fs.disk.FilePathDisk.createDirectory(FilePathDisk.java:347)
> hapi-fhir-jpaserver-start    |  ... 143 common frames omitted

Tried to change the owner, change the folder, but none of it helped.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same Error Message. Within the application.yaml the Search Engine was enabled and the default location where unchanged:

```
###    These settings will enable fulltext search with lucene or elastic
   hibernate.search.enabled: true
### lucene parameters
#      hibernate.search.backend.type: lucene
#      hibernate.search.backend.directory.type: local-filesystem
#      hibernate.search.backend.directory.root: target/lucenefiles
```

This leads to the the "/app/target" path - and the subfolder "/app/target/lucenefiles". This could be similar if your using the H2 Database without a Volume, as this Folder is read-only inside the Docker-Image so no files or folders can be created.

I could solve this by adding a volume to the docker container for /app/target

```
  docker run -p 8080:8080 -v /your/local/path:/app/target hapiproject/hapi:latest
```

This works well for Testing/Development; better would be to use a custom application.yaml with dedicated settings.